# how does the value of "this" in vuex store module actions determined?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have two actions in two different modules:

```
unload: ({ commit, state }) => {
  console.log(this);
  commit('UNLOAD_LOCATIONS_GROUPED');
  Object.keys(state.providerList).forEach((npi) => {
    store.unregisterModule(`locationsGroup/providersList/${npi.toString()}`);
  });
},
```

---

```
unload({ getters, commit }) {
  console.log(this);
  getters.list.forEach((provider) => {
    this.unregisterModule(['providers', 'list', provider.npi]);
  });
  commit('UNLOAD_PROVIDERS');
},
```

---

When I see the value of this in the console, I see that one is the store(what I want) and the other is an object that seems to represent the module when logged looks like this `{a: {...}}` Diving into the later object looks like all the same properties of that actions module.

What is the context of `this` in an action or how is it derived? As it doesn't seem to be consistent.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

Comment: oh my, i didn't even notice my typo there =( thanks so much